# 3" stress relief

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a Siemens panel with a 3 inches hole.

[image]

All I found is this stress relief that is smaller (about 2.7 inches) and without thread.

[image]

Is there wire stress relief for 3inches hole? If none. How do I use the smaller tube above in the 3 inches hole?

Comment: "strain relief"

Comment: What sort of thing are you trying to put through this 3" KO?

Comment: Pair of AWG 2 subpanel feeder wires and 6 pairs of 10 awg load wires

Comment: Aren't those feeders required to be in conduit? Strain relief doesn't usually come into play with them.

Comment: If i use 3" conduit. How will i attach it to the panel hole in the picture in original post?

Comment: @Jtl what type of conduit are you trying to use for this? (PVC? EMT? GRC/RMC?)

Comment: Pvc. How will i attach it to the metal hole?

Comment: Is this conduit or cable bundle longer than 24 inches?

Answer (score 2):

You glue [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-3-in-PVC-Male-Terminal-Adapter-Case-of-5-E943L-CAR/202204396?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-6_CONDUIT-BOXES-FITTINGS%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000034238990%7C58700003946879308%7C92700031954573793&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhcmT0ciK4AIVC4hpCh1fGQEaEAQYASABEgKMnPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) on the end of your PVC pipe...

[image]

Then you stick it through the hole and screw it down into the hole with [a 3" nut](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-in-Rigid-Conduit-Locknut-61930/100171404?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-202204396-_-100171404-_-N).

[image]

And that's it.

---

Remember 310.15(b)(3)(a): if the conduit run is 24" or longer, then aside from the normal current limits on wire, additional derates apply with 2+ circuits.  You must go look up the highest ampacity permitted for your wiring type in [table 310.15(b)(16](http://www.barr-thorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/digest-176-nec-tables.pdf)) and derate to: 80% for 2-3 circuits, 70% for 4 circuits,and 50% for 5-10 circuits.  So for instance your 10AWG NM cable uses the 60C column, the rating the is 30A, since there are 7 circuits you must derate it 50% for 15A.

Generally this isn't an issue with <=3 circuits per conduit.

Answer (score 0):

You meant "cord strain relief".

After a quick search I couldn't find a 3" strain relief, although it might exist, besides a $400 aluminum one which probably doesn't fit your needs.

Instead, my recommendation is a simple 3" PVC pipe fitting. Check out this $1 3" PVC pipe fitting which you may be able to retrofit to your purposes.

[image]
https://www.homedepot.com/p/NIBCO-3-in-PVC-DWV-Coupling-C4801HD3/100343559

You could simply epoxy it in is my first thought, depending on your purposes; or, you could try fitting a simply 3" rubber grommet so the pvc would stay in place.

Moreover, once you start looking at "*3" PVC fittings*" you'll find so many things that I'm sure there is something you can use for this purpose, and probably for just a few dollars.

p.s. you can use a hacksaw to cut the PVC to size so it is slimmer :)

Comment: You mean 3 inches hole are not common in any load centers? What is the average diameter holes? And what do those with 3 inches hole actually use?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Can you clarify your specific usage?

Comment: The usage is just to protect the edges of the 3 inch hole from cutting any wire.. so jus need 3" strain relief? Arent 3 inches strain relief common?

Comment: I don't know, but I am pretty sure that you aren't going to get much better than one dollar for this PVC fitting no matter what you get, so if I were you I would just get this one dollar PVC fitting and be done with it :) Hope it helps, please let me know how your project goes! :)

Comment: p.s. just getting this dollar PVC fitting that is the correct size is way better than trying to retrofit your wrong-size 2.7" piece, so just get this one dollar 3" pvc piece and there you have it :)

Comment: @diyuser -- this hardware is NOT the correct thing for the job here -- a cable needs to be strain-relieved to the panel, and this won't use it.  Furthermore, it'll get the OP a thumbs *down* from the AHJ...

Comment: Isnt the purpose of strain relief so the wires wont get the sharp edge of the cut panel cutting them..so why is the pvc tube not sufficient? The pvc edge is not sharp either?

Comment: No. Strain relief relieves the actual electrical connection of any chance of strain. You don't want tension on the lugs or the wire arrangement in the panel getting tugged around. Yes, it does protect the wiring, but that's a secondary effect.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel well it depends if he's just doing a small project or if he's doing something professional that has to be done "the right way". OP said that he only wants to prevent the wires from being cut on the sides of the metal, so thus my answer to answer his inquiry and information given. While this indeed **is not a professional solution**, it will be fine for a small DIY retrofit where he's looking to save money, which seems to be the fact seeing that he actually wanted to retrofit a wrong-size PVC pipe! Since he would accept doing that, it would be better to use the right size 3" pvc.